# Can you carry POST variables page to page if redirecting?

Tags: php, variables, post, redirect

To start, I am not asking if I can create a POST response from one page to another without use of a form or one of the similar questions which may come to mind. At the start of several of my pages, I automatically force https security with the following require statement:

```
<?php
if($port == 80) {
    if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
        header('Location: http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        exit;
    }
} elseif ($port == 443) {
    if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {
        header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

where $port is set directly before calling the PHP require. In some instances where directing from a http to https (or simply changing the URL by person), any POST variables generated from the form on page 1 would be lost on the redirect.

Maybe I am asking the same question as the 'no form' but if so, any advice on how to handle based on the requirements is appreciated.

### Thoughts

I **could** put everything into SESSION but this seems like a huge waste of resources. Unless somebody can really show otherwise, I don't consider this a solution.

Comment: A huge waste of resources? I don't agree with that. It's maybe a couple of extra lines, if you set it up right.

Comment: By dint of it not being `https`, if someone is submitting a form and you have not included a `https` link in the action attribute, you've already lost the security before you do a roundtrip. So you might want to make sure it doesn't happen instead of trying to essentially resubmit by way of `header()`. FWIW.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - having to set and unset thousands and thousands of session variables page to page seems like a waste of resources to me, yes. That said, you make a good point on setting the action attribute itself.

Comment: A huge waste of resources?  That's exactly what SESSION was designed for..

Comment: @tandu - SESSION variables were meant to carry variables from page to page based on user input, specifically forms. There are SEVERAL pages on sites which have use for POST variables (used once) where SESSION variables kept in memory are not 'as' valuable. I was looking for a solution I did not have to build a page which took the post variables, put them into session, redirected to SSL port 443 THEN took the session variables, handled them appropriately and unset each one (because they have zero value page to page). This is not an enrollment form per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen other questions that ask essentially the same question, and I believe it's not really possible to do what you want effectively. My own opinion is it's going to be a whole lot MORE work to make what you want than just to deploy `SESSION`:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!is_array($_SESSION['posted'])) {
    $_SESSION['posted'] = array('test'=>'test');
} else {
    $_POST = $_SESSION['posted'];
    unset($_SESSION['posted']);
}

echo '<pre>';
echo "<strong>POST:</strong>\n";
print_r($_POST);
echo "\n";
echo "<strong>SESSION:</strong>\n";
print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

** Note: I don't have SSL setup on my server, so I can't demonstrate that specifically. This is meant to demonstrate reinflating a `POST` array only from a `SESSION`-stored array.*

http://jfcoder.com/test/postsession.php (Refresh to see it change.)

So if you can rebuild a `POST` array so easily^, why not just do that? The resources needed to do it across requests that are needed and actually used I believe will be negligible, since you're really only doing it for a moment.

Unless you have hundreds of thousand or millions of concurrent hits, I can't imagine the above being a problem resource wise. If it was, then just process it before redirecting. They've already sent the data in the clear at that point anyway.

*^ Also, you will need to handle file uploads as well, if you need that.*

Comment: Jared - I am going to accept your answer temporarily based on the sole fact of 'not really possible to do what you want effectively'. In your example, the SESSION variable had to be set prior to the page you describe. As a reminder, the form was submitted to page 2, if page 2 recognized it was not port 443, it automatically redirected to itself. The SESSION variable would have to be set =  POST before this then unset on subsequent pages. Seems like a pain but perhaps the only way it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to do any server-side storage, use a 307 redirect.  Should work with any HTTP/1.1 compliant browser... however note that not only will you be using twice the bandwidth for the POST data (since it is sent twice), but browsers are required to ask for permission before resubmitting to the new URL.

`header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');`
`header('location: .... );`

[edit: Storing it server-side temporarily is probably better.  Avoiding the need to redirect at all is best.]